# What's the meaning of W suffix for thumb-2 instruction?

Tags: arm, thumb

There is a w suffix for thumb-2 instruction as below, how does it change the semantic of the instruction without it? The search result is very noisy and I didn't get the answer.

`addw r0, r1, #0`

Comment: It helps the assembler pick between what thumb2 can do that thumb cant.  Maybe not this case but you may have an instruction that can be encoded either thumb or thumb2, by using something like this you can basically ask for a certain encoding.  A shorter answer is "try it" write a line of code with the same without, assemble then disassemble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see ADDW in [Cortex-M3 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Chdbhfja.html) Table 2-5

```
Data operations with large immediate
ADDW and SUBW have a 12-bit immediate. This means they can replace many from memory literal loads.
```

It is also mentioned in [Quick Reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf)

```
add wide T2 ADD Rd, Rn, #<imm12>
```

Looks like the assembler would recognize the immediate constant <= 12 bits, and do the needful.

In the context where you see it, it is an ordinary "add".

Comment: To make sense of this, historic 16-bit thumb add/sub only support 8-bit constants.  The ARM mode always supports 12bit.  As per dwelch, this will be a 32bit thumb2 op-code.  You don't want to use it for `addw r0,r0,#1`, but need it for `addw r0,r0,#257`.  I think this was added so that *unified* assembler can automatically pick the correct encoding when you have a constant that is out of the traditional thumb range.  My 2cents.  Btw, I find *thumb2* confusing.  It is not a mode but is more like a bunch of additional *thumb* instruction, like armv6, armv7 expand the op-codes for regular ARM.

Comment: @artlessnoise You can use `add r0, #257`. Assembler would just create encoding T4. So you don't need to use it unless you want to be explicitly specify you want it for some reason. ARM ARM also tells the story in this way.

Comment: @auselen  My point was that the `addw` 32-bit encoding only makes sense for constants bigger than 255.  I know the assembler will select automatically; other uses are people trying to understand `objdump` or *disassembled* source.  Often these programs will be explicit.  So, for assembler you should just use `add` (I didn't ask this question...); I suspect that `addw` with constants less than 256 maybe deprecated at some point to extend the instruction range.  The information is probably only useful to look at disassembler output... for that use case, this is a **good** question.

Answer (score 6):

Simply enough, W means "wide".  It is the 32-bit version of the instruction, whereas most Thumb instructions are 16 bits wide.  The wide instructions often have bigger immediates or can address more registers.

Edit: Some of the comments seem confused about the difference between `addw` and `add.w`.  The only essential difference is how the immediate is encoded.

```
add.w:  imm32 = ThumbExpandImm(i:imm3:imm8);
addw:   imm32 = ZeroExtend(i:imm3:imm8, 32);
```

Comment: Now go on and explain difference between add.w and addw

Comment: As @auselen mentioned, you are explaining .w, not w suffix.

Answer (score 3):

Different encodings of an instruction should have distinguishing syntaxes so when you disassemble a binary you should notice which encoding was used. This also helps when you assemble back a disassembled binary, resulting binary should be the one you start with.

In your case using `addw` instead of `add` doesn't change the semantic of instruction as it is an add operation. However it certainly forces assembler to produce `Encoding T4` (32-bit) of `add` instruction, as that's dictated by the specification.

Summary when assembling you can use just `add` mnemonic and assembler would choose the right encoding and you can see that in the object dump.

```
int f1(int i) {
    asm volatile("add r0, #0");
    asm volatile("add r0, #257");
}

00000000 <f1>:
   0:   f100 0000   add.w   r0, r0, #0
   4:   f200 1001   addw    r0, r0, #257    ; 0x101
   8:   4770        bx  lr
   a:   bf00        nop
```

Comment: If you know the ARM ARM, then 'T[1-4]' encoding makes sense, but I don't know if everyone knows T1-T4 encoding.  There are four encodings; cc set with `adds rx,ry, #imm3`, `adds rx, #imm8` setting cc, `add.w rx, ry, #special` (conditons yes or no) and finally `addw rx, ry, #imm12` where you may not set conditions.  Also, you get different encodings if inside an `IT` block.  For most people they all do the same thing except for conditions set.  Try `add r0,#0xabababab` for how strange T3 is.  And there are multiple ways to do some additions, which is why a disassembler shows the extra stuff.