# Which instruction encoding is supported by a ARM processor, particularly a Cortex M0, STM32F0 one for example

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, thumb, instruction-encoding

Confused about instruction encoding supported by my core (ie. T1, T2, etc)

Having the STM32F0 series Cortex-M0 programming manual, I found that
https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/pm0215-stm32f0-series-cortexm0-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf

*"The Cortex®-M0 processor implements the Arm®v6-M architecture, which is based on the 16-bit Thumb®
instruction set and includes Thumb-2 technology."*

Ok, so went for ARMv6M generic manual here
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0419/c/
https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f8feef5f86e16515cdbf7e4?token=

And for example ADD (register) instruction has 2 flavors

[image]

Both of them are present in CPU?

Ok, so T1 updates flags and T2 doesn't, good to know :)

But later on in ARM manual says:

*...If  is omitted, this register is the same as  and encoding T2
is preferred to encoding T1 if both are available.*

So if both are available, how do I know if this is true for my STM32F?
And in general, based on what criteria are these T1/T2 used by manufacturers?
In STM32 programming manual I cannot find such info.

For NXP's LPC824 for example (also a Cortex M0) CPU exact type is missing, so guessing it's the same ARMv6M type.

Comment: All ARMv6-M processors support all instruction encodings listed in the document.

Comment: Preferred is a note to compiler and assembler developers.  There is no formal arm assembler language (a BNF, yacc, etc) that is managed by ARM.  So if an assembler sees `add R0, R0, R1`, it should prefer the T2 encoding.  If the text `add R0, R1, R2`, it needs to use the T1 encoding.  *available* in this context means either will work for an assembler or compiler to map text to binary.  Sometimes options exist such as `add.w` to always select a particular encoding.  [The meaning of 'w' suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203745/whats-the-meaning-of-w-suffix-for-thumb-2-instruction).

Comment: Encoding T1 is 'thumb-1' or legacy thumb.  Note that registers are 3 bits (R0-R7) and do not encode for registers above R7.  Thumb1 always sets flags.  Encoding T2 allows a destination above R7.  In calculating a pointer, you may not want condition codes.  If you are bound checking an array, the condition codes need to be set.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Instruction_sets mentions the instructions that were added in ARMv7-M and are *not* available on M0 / M0+ / M1 (CBZ, CBNZ, IT).  IDK if that's an exhaustive list.  It also points out that they include a few Thumb-2 instructions.

Comment: T1 does not mean thumb1 and T2 does not mean thumb 2.  Some of the descriptions have more than one instruction per so they put a T1 for the first one and T2, T3, etc for others.   all 16 bit ones are original thumb.  the 2x16 ones are all thumb2 extensions.  armv6-m added a couple of dozen to the original armv7-m added over 100 on top of that.

Comment: @old_timer  I know it doesn't mean that, but in this case, it is.  When I referred to T1, I meant that **THIS** encoding as a Thumb-1 style add (low registers and always setting conditions).  Also, I suspect that if you investigate, it is a Thumb-1 encoding from way back.  It also goes to the purpose of why it might exist when other encoding might do the same thing. Co-incidentally named 'T1'.

Comment: @artlessnoise I was actually not responding to your comment, but to the poster in general, deleted my long answer, so narrowed it down to perhaps the confusion is T1 and T2 meaning thumb 1 and thumb 2, not sure if that was the confusion here.  but that is not the case.  Arm used A1,A2,A3, T1, T2, T3 to indicate arm vs thumb encodings which you wont see in the armv6-m that well but if look at full sized armv7-a this naming scheme starts to make a lot more sense.  No feedback from the OP so not sure where this question should go from here.

Comment: @old_timer  I see.  It is confusing (as are many things about ARM naming).  Good point.